# OSX copy DVD data while resetting permissions

Tags: macos, permissions, terminal, dvd

I have a DVD of .dwg files I need to copy from a DVD to my mac. The files are organised in a folder structure on the DVD as well.

The problem seems to be that while I can cope some files across the folders have permissions as read only. As the copy process isn't complete the files do not have permission to be written to these read only folders. ~70% transfer is achieved.

Resetting permissions and copying manually would take a days.

Is there a way, perhaps in terminal, I can force the dvd to copy all data? Or, a way to copy with new read/write permissions allowing for the DVD to copy completely.

Any help greatly appreciated!!